# Допустимо ли в данном случае оформить мысли персонажа курсивом, а не с помощью кавычек?

Tags: прямая-речь, диалог

*Если доведётся бежать, не мешкая скину рюкзак где-нибудь по пути*, - жуткие мысли забарабанили в голове, покрывая и без того замерзшее тело колючими мурашками. - *Если доведется… Но от кого?*

Comment: Можно курсивом, но, мне кажется, что тире в таком случае не нужно, так как это всё мысли одного человека: *Если доведётся бежать, не мешкая скину рюкзак где-нибудь по пути*... жуткие мысли забарабанили в голове, покрывая и без того замерзшее тело колючими мурашками... *Если доведется… но от кого?* - то есть можно художественно и разнообразно обыграть через оформление внутреннюю речь человека, и пойти дальше, нарушая классические формы, создать своё, авторское, повествование. Можно добавить капс, можно прерывание и тп. Это читается и это главное.

Comment: Кроме того можно использовать различные шрифты. Текст видимый - это художественный инструмент.

Comment: @Буратино, спасибо огромное! Полезно)